# passing parameters to another action in rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I want to pass an id from an html page to another action in the same controller so that i can retrieve raow from the database.

my link statement looks like this:

```
<%= button_to "Add",{:controller => "demo", :action => "Added"}, :id => "1" %>
```

my controller:

```
class DemoController < ApplicationController;
  def index
    render(:action => 'Category')
  end

 def current_html
 end

 def added
   @add = Add.find(:id)
 end
end
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= button_to "Add", {:controller => "demo", :action => "Added",  :id=>"1"}  %>
```

and then in `added` action use,

```
@add = Add.find(params[:id])
```

In case of same controller you can omit `:controller => "demo"`

you can use `link_to` then `add button class` or even `hidden_field` to pass the id

Comment: The reason i want to do this is to populate a table in another html using @add on clicking the link button_to.. could u show me that??

Comment: using `@add = Add.find(params[:id])` in the controller, i will get the database row.. i want to simultaneouly populate a table in another html page.
something like this:
`<%  @add.each do |add| %>
       <tr>
       </tr>
<% end %>`
how to change @add.each to use only selected value?

Comment: It's a single record now, when there are multiple records you have to use each `method`